# MS Project 2010 and SP 2013 Integration

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, ms-project

Could someone please point me to the right direction? I am having issue integrating my MS Project 2010 Professional version into SharePoint 2013.

Below is the project plan I am trying to sync to SP.
[image: Project Image]

Below is the SP list after the sync was done. Why is it that I can't get a view similar to project where the subtasks are shown right away and in one page. I can't do a drilled down in SP. I always need to click my the main task to get to the list of sub tasks. Then I will go back to my Project Task view to look for my other project plan, click it and see the other sub tasks. How do I make it look like the view in my Project?

This is how the main task in SP looks now.
[image: MainTask]

If I click one of my test projects, I would see the sub tasks.
[image: SubTasks]

Is there something I can do to fix this?

Thank you all in advance for your kind response or questions.

Answer (score 0):

The `Project Tasks` just shows the **Summary Tasks** in your Project Plan,

**In case,** you need to show All Tasks by default and avoid the drill down to show the sub-tasks, you should use the `All Tasks` View.

[image]

---

To Set `All Tasks` View as the **default**, you should

- Click on `All Tasks` view.
- From the above ribbon, List tab > Click on `Modify View`.
- Check `Make this the default view.`

[image]